# How to fetch the exact input word user asked in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My app has category and category also has vocab, so if user search and input value has fallen into vocab so it will return the `symbol` value.
For example: my vocab is

```
Chinese {"Chinese" "noodles" "soup"}
```

and user search for soup, so the input value it will return to my api is Chinese. which is fine but I want to give user a message like "Here are the good soup restaurants".

How will i get the exact input word from user?

Answer (score 0):

The Bixby platform will return a symbol back if the utterance matches one of the items in the vocabulary.

But if you wanted to get the actual utterance, maybe you can change the Category type to `text` and map the vocab -> category by yourself.

Comment: I didn't get that, if I will definitely my category as text, will I be able to define  vocab for it?

Comment: No. But you will have access to the actual word ("Soup") spoken by the user if that is important to the end-user experience you want to create. (compared to when you defined Category as `enum` and had a `vocabulary` for it but no access to the spoken word). 

You can raise a Feature Request for Product Management to consider returning the spoken word (in addition to the symbol) at https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests f